# How to show error console log for stylelint Node API?

Tags: stylelint

When using the stylelint on the CLI like `stylelint "**/_main.scss"` and there's an error in the file, it errors out and logs something like [image]

However when using the [Node API](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/node-api) for it, the log is just an output with some key values with the error as a string value. How do I get the output to error out just like when using the CLI? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default formatter for the stylelint Node API is `"json"`, whereas the stylelint CLI uses the `"string"` formatter.

You can use the `formatter` property to use the `"string"` formatter when using the Node API, like so:

```
var stylelint = require("stylelint");

stylelint
  .lint({
    code: "a { unknown: 0 }",
    config: { rules: { "property-no-unknown": true } },
    formatter: "string"
  })
  .then(function({ output, errored }) {
    console.log(output);
    if (errored) process.exit(2);
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.error(err.stack);
  });
```

The [Developer guide documentation](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/node-api#the-returned-promise) details the structure of the returned promise. You can use `output` to display the results from the formatter and `errored` to set the exit code.

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't seem to produce the same results as the CLI. It doesn't error out and only shows the output of: https://imgur.com/a/Yp5u8Ag

Comment: I've updated the answer to correct the output and show how to change the exit code.